# Javascript in SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, 2013, modal-dialog

I have Created one aspx page and write  in Main Content. I want to call SharePoint Modal Popup script on click event in sharepoint:MenuItemTemplate.
How can i call javascript for modal popup in  in Sharepoint 2013?

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Please explain your question, not able to get your requirement properly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Anuja, I have modified my question..

Answer (score 0):

```
 menuitemtemplate.ClientOnClickNavigateUrl ="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:'http:/sharedev/sitecreate.aspx', width:200px });";
```

or you can even try with **ClientOnClickScript** instead of ClientOnClickNavigateUrl

Hope this helps,

Comment: does the above one helps to you?